# Align divs next to each other in container and make container take width of children

Tags: css, reactjs

I want a *container* div:

- Which should take width of its children.
- I want its children to align horizontally.
- And container should be single horizontal line

I don't want to use flex because then CSS tries to squeeze the children in containers width.
This is solution I came up with **which seems to work** but I want to better understand the properties I used, hence the questions.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './style.css';
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map((x) => {
            return <div className="card">{x}</div>;
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

css

```
    .container {
      display: inline-block;
      background: red;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    .card {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
```

- My main question is: why do we need **two inline-block** usages? (one on the container one on the cards)
- You can see I had to add  `white-space: nowrap;` was it necessary in this situation?

Mainly I am interested in above questions, but if you *additionally* have a more elegant solution also, you can post it.

Comment: "_I don't want to use flex because then CSS tries to squeeze the children in containers width"_ - do you mean that parent takes full width?

Comment: @kinduser yeah then the container div takes parents width I think and tries to squeeze its children inside

Answer (score -2):

display: inline, the major difference is that display: inline-block allows to set a width and height on the element.

Also, with display: inline-block, the top and bottom margins/paddings are respected, but with display: inline they are not.

Comment: why was it needed to use `inline-block` **2 times**? You also didn't answer the 2nd question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    background: red;
    // Add Gap between the cards 
    gap: 3rem
  }
  
  .card {
    flex: 0 1 100px; 
    max-width: 100px

  }
```